# why my struct takes more memory than requested?

Tags: c++, memory

I am testing the following code with Visual Studio 2019 Diagnostic Tools.

It says that memory consumption is 55 KB instead of the 20 KB I previously calculated. As you can see, it is much more memory than I thought and I don't know why.

**What I want to know is:** what is happening or how could I calculate the correct memory consumption? (since I don't always have the "Diagnostic Tools" at hand.)

```
#include <iostream>

#define TEST_SIZE_ARR 1000

struct Node
{
    Node(int)
        : id(0),
        time(0),
        next(0),
        back(0)
    {}

    int id;
    int time;
    Node* next;
    Node* back;
};

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    std::cout << "= Node =" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Array size: " << sizeof(Node*) << " * " << TEST_SIZE_ARR << " = " << sizeof(Node*) * TEST_SIZE_ARR << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Element size: " << sizeof(Node) << " * " << TEST_SIZE_ARR << " = " << sizeof(Node) * TEST_SIZE_ARR << std::endl;

    Node **dataArr = new Node*[TEST_SIZE_ARR]; //break point
    for (counter = 0; counter < TEST_SIZE_ARR; counter++) //break point
    {
        dataArr[counter] = new Node(counter);
    }
    counter++; //break point

    return 0;
}
```

Console:

```
Array size: 4 * 1000 = 4000
Element size: 16 * 1000 = 16000
```

Diagnostic tool:

```
Array size: 3.94 KB
Element size: 50.78 KB
```

Comment: There are no [tag:bit-fields] here.

Comment: If you're programming for a big machine, use std::vector instead, and make it allocate all the memory in the constructor (it will default initialize everything so you don't need the for loop). If you're programming an embedded, you might consider using a custom allocator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diagnostic tool is measuring an allocation overhead of 36 bytes per allocation.

50.78 KB is 52000 bytes, or 52 bytes per element allocation.  Minus 16 is 36 bytes.

4000 bytes with 36 bytes overhead is 4036 bytes, which is 3.94 KB.

The heap has to track which blocks of memory are in use and which are not.  Possibly your diagnostic tool has additional overhead and self measures stupidly; I don't know.

In your case, it appears to be adding an additional 36 bytes per value returned from `new`.  Your system seems to be 32 bit pointers (ick), so that is enough room for 9 pointers.  You probably want to include the size of each allocation in its block, which is 4 bytes on a 32 bit system.  That leaves 8 pointers.

What your heap is using those 8 pointers for, I don't know.  Maybe a skip list, or a red black tree, or even some buffers around each allocation to detect memory corruption because you profiled a debug build and heap.

In general, small heap allocations are inefficient and a bad idea.  It is one of the many reasons why block containers, like std vector, are good idea, and node containers are iffy.